# how to merge similar key values in same keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, web-frontend, xsjs

```js
var array = [{
  "ADJUSTMENT_TYPE": "AP0001",
  "REV_TYPE": "R"
}, {
  "ADJUSTMENT_TYPE": "AP0001",
  "REV_TYPE": "E"
}, {
  "ADJUSTMENT_TYPE": "AP0001",
  "REV_TYPE": "N"
}];
```

I want it to be like this

```js
[{
  "ADJUSTMENT_TYPE": "AP0001",
  "REV_TYPE": "R",
  "E",
  "N"
}]
```

I want this in javascript. can anyone help me

thanks in advance

Comment: The output which you are expecting is incorrect json object. JSON objects must have key and values

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current example does not check for duplicates `REV_TYPE`:

```js
const array = [
    { ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: 'AP0001', REV_TYPE: 'R' },
    { ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: 'AP0002', REV_TYPE: 'E' },
    { ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: 'AP0001', REV_TYPE: 'N' },
    { ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: 'AP0001', REV_TYPE: 'N' },
    { ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: 'AP0002', REV_TYPE: 'N' },
    { ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: 'AP0002', REV_TYPE: 'N' },
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const findType = acc.find(t => t.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE === val.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE);

    if (findType) {
        findType.REV_TYPE.push(val.REV_TYPE);
    } else {
        acc.push({ ADJUSTMENT_TYPE: val.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE, REV_TYPE: [val.REV_TYPE] });
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks its working